# How do you output html as code on asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to dump out some HTML I am rendering in a C# class on an ASPX page. But not as the rendered HTML but the actual HTML before the browser renders it.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd like to know this. Code and pre tags work for everything except HTML. I don't want to tell you to use XML refernces which is the only work around as the answer as Im sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Server.HtmlEncode should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()

EDIT

If you take a look in reflector, you'll see that Server.HtmlEncode() calls HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()